# How can I start an HTA application from R?

Tags: r, hta

I want to start an HTA application from R but can not manage to.

I tried `system2("test.hta")` as well as `system2("mshta test.hta")` and `system2("cmd /c test.hta")`.

This always gives me a message like `Warning message: running command '"mshta test.hta"' had status 127`.

Running the same HTA from a cmd command line works fine using the command lines `test.hta` or `cmd /c test.hta`. On the other hand `mshta test.hta` does not work although I would expect it to work.

Any ideas where the problem is or how I could manage to call my HTA from R?

(I am running R 3.2.2 on Windows 7 Professional)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shell()` rather than `system2()`. The latter is expecting an executable (`.exe` or `.com`) or batch file (`.bat`). This restriction isn't given in the help file for `system2()` but is in the help file for `system()`, for which `system2()` is an interface.

Make sure to include the full path to the HTA.

Comment: For me, this even works with relative paths to the HTA. Thanks a lot!